# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to delete a user profile, when the last logout time was 2 years ago and there is no current activities were made during that time.

This is the problem encountered when i run the code:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`spwtd-test`.`training_user_answers`, CONSTRAINT
>   `training_user_answers_training_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`training_user_id`) REFERENCES `training_users` (`id`))

this is the snippet code in **loginController**:

```
if ($completed = UserSyllabus::where('is_completed',1)->first())
       {$aa = UserAnswer::where('training_user_id')
        $userss = User::where('login_id', $request->login_id)
       ->where( 'last_logout', '<', Carbon::now()->subYears(2))
       ->delete();}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to delete a User but an entry in your table UserAnswer is bind to User ( using the foreign key training_user_id ). 
You need to delete the UserAnswer, before deleting the User itself.

Comment: hi sir, thank you for your reply. I tried to delete the fk in the UserAnswer. but it didnt work.

Comment: below is my code:$users = User::where('login_id', $request->login_id)
           ->where( 'last_logout', '<', Carbon::now()->subYears(2));

           foreach ($users as $usr) {
               $UserAns = UserAnswer::where('training_user_id',$usr->id)->get()->first();

                $UserAns->delete();
                
           }
           //->where('is_complete',1)
           $users->delete();

Comment: To select the answer you are using : ->get()->first() . If you only have one answer per user ,use directly ->first() ( remove the ->get() )

Comment: Thank you sooo much @RomainV, your answer gave a clear clue to solve my issue, I had to delete the related foreign key first and then only delete the parent row!